# Multiple instances of views with Prism and MEF

Tags: wpf, prism, mef, instances

I need to instanciate many instances of the same View of a Prism module.
I am using MEF: The Codeplex version has the ExportFactory attribute that allows multiple instance creation but Prism uses the .Net desktop version that has not this ExportFactory attribute. I tried to make Prism work with the CodePlex version but it seems this is not possible..

I found the Composition.Initialization.Desktop thing but I did not succeed in using it.

Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PartCreationPolicy attribute and set it to NonShared.

Or, you could also Export and Import a factory class that you then use to build the desired class.

Answer (score 0):

The next version of MEF for the desktop will have ExportFactory.  You can download a preview from the [MEF CodePlex site](http://mef.codeplex.com/), which has support for ExportFactory on the desktop.

Comment: Yes, but the class needing this ExportFactory is a Prism Module and so must have a reference on the .Net MEF which has not the ExportFactory attribute ...

Comment: You could get the source code for Prism and compile it against the Codeplex version of MEF.  Or you could look at MefContrib (http://mefcontrib.codeplex.com/), I think it may have something that enables ExportFactory or something similar in the .NET 4 version of MEF.

Comment: @okilele See my previous comment (which I forgot to mark as a reply to you)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I recompiled Prism with the MEF Codeplex version and this works.